# refreshing div every 10 second duplicate the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using jquery it auto refresh after 10 seconds and every time it refresh it duplicate the div for one time and refresh both of the div's again.

the duplicate happens only one time ..

code:

```
           <div class="tournament-users">
     <span class="tournament_reg_teams_num">0/8></span>
     </div>
```

js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var autoLoad = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
      $('.tournament_reg_teams_num').load('normal-l.php .tournament_reg_teams_num').fadeIn(\"fast\");
   }, 10000); // refresh page every 10 seconds
</script>
```

and what i get after 10 seconds is :

```
       <div class="tournament-users">
 <span class="tournament_reg_teams_num">0/8></span>
 <span class="tournament_reg_teams_num">0/8></span>
 </div>
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: `$('.tournament_reg_teams_num').load('normal-l.php .tournament_reg_teams_num').fadeIn(\"fast\");` why does it haves a class after calling php? is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Before appeding you have to flush `div` content using `empty()`.

Please try

```
$('.tournament-users').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an id instead of a class. Also you could try to build a wrapper for your `tournament_reg_teams_num` and load it into that.

Try something like this for example:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper_tournament_reg_teams_num">
    <span id="tournament_reg_teams_num">0/8</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var autoLoad = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
      $('#wrapper_tournament_reg_teams_num').load('normal-l.php #tournament_reg_teams_num').fadeIn(\"fast\");
   }, 10000);
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test2">test2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var count = 0;
//function autoload : it return the setInterval function 
var autoload = setInterval(function(){
    //(You can do what you want here, depending on what you want to do)
    count += 1;

    //Here, I remove the content of "test" element
    $('.test').empty();

    //I create the new element and add it to "test" element
    var element = $('<div></div>').addClass('test2').html('test2');
    $('.test').append(element);

    console.log(refresh);
}, 10000);

//If you have to stop the refresh
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('clearInterval');
    clearInterval(autoload);
}, 6000)
```

This is only an exemple of auto refresh, hope it can help you !